# how to use dimensions with d3 parcoords

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimensions

I am new to d3 and i am trying to use http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/

Here you see the minimalistic example from the website.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3.parcoords.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d3.parcoords.css">
<div id="example" class="parcoords" style="width:360px;height:150px"></div>

<script>
var data = [
  [0,-0,0,0,0,3 ],
  [1,-1,1,2,1,6 ],
  [2,-2,4,4,0.5,2],
  [3,-3,9,6,0.33,4],
  [4,-4,16,8,0.25,9]
];

var pc = d3.parcoords()("#example")
  .data(data)
  .render()
  .ticks(3)
  .createAxes();
</script>
```

I want some dimensions not to be shown and tried different approaches with # parcoords.dimensions(dimensions). How would you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the fiddle Gerrat set-up but doesn't look to have worked the way I thought it should.  In that fiddle the names of dimensions have been removed, but the link or lines between the dimension still represent the original data.  This behaviour seems odd to me and it might be a bug.

Anyway, I've set-up a fiddle that pre-filters the data using:

```
data.forEach( function (e,j) { 
    var temp ={};
    filteredDimensions.forEach ( function (d,i) {
        temp[d] = e[d]
    })
    filteredData.push(temp)
})
```

With a working fiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h65Cs/)

Comment: The names weren't `removed`, the OP just never provided any.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your `.dimensions()` call after `.ticks()`, and before `.createAxes()`:

```
var pc = d3.parcoords()("#example")
  .data(data)
  .render()
  .ticks(3)
  .dimensions([1,2,4])
  .render()
  .createAxes();
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PSjYj/6/)

After looking at user1614080's solution, he just filters the data ahead-of-time, which is easy, and always available, but not what you asked for.  I tried using his example (with the names), and just used the names for the dimensions (jsFiddle [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/h65Cs/2/)).  The way I did it works just fine with named dimensions too.

The dimensions just need to come somewhere after the `.render()`, but I'm not sure why.

**EDIT**: Finally figured out why this wasn't showing right.  `.render()` needs to be called after the dimensions are updated (alludes to it slightly [here](https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates#parcoords_interactive)).  Both examples updated to fix the inflection points between the axes.

Comment: thanks also for your answer. I always wonder how methods have to be ordered. Do you by chance know a tutorial or do you have good explanation?

Comment: Nope...I just tried to get it to work, and thought I had.  Maybe not.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, I was right.  This `is` the way you filter on dimensions (I added a 2nd jsfiddle)

Comment: The dimensions(dimensions) call is filtering out the axis for dimensions, but if you look at the lines that join the dimensions together they haven't been filtered, so that the inflection points do not occur at the dimension axis.  To put it another way the axis's are being filtered (removed), but not the connections between the axis's, so that the lines between each dimension remain remains the same before and after filtering.

Comment: @user1614080:  You are right!  When I looked at the lines initially, they looked the same.  Upon closer inspection, the inflection points are wrong.  Can't see how this isn't a bug.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: by chance, do you know how one could also force a specific order for the axes? So that if you call   `.dimensions([4,2,1])` or `.dimensions(['protein','name','sodium'])`, that would predefine their order in the chart? Currently, it seems they are sorted alphabetically/numerically.